# Does GNU Classpath exception allow me to take parts of the library, link with them and distribute the resulting executable on my terms?

Tags: gpl, derivative-works, exceptions

GNU Classpath exception says I can *link this library with independent modules to produce an executable, regardless of the license terms of these independent modules, and to copy and distribute the resulting executable under terms of your choice*.

Note ***this library*** wording. It sounds like I can take the library code as a whole, compile it into a separate module and then link my code to that separate module.

What if I don't need the whole library code? Am I allowed to take only parts of the library (only some functions), compile those parts into a separate module and then link my code to that separate module and distribute the resulting executable on my terms?

Answer (score 1):

> What if I don't need the whole library code? Am I allowed to take only parts of the library (only some functions), compile those parts into a separate module and then link my code to that separate module and distribute the resulting executable on my terms?

IMHO yes. And you would still need to attribute and redistribute the corresponding source code of this library subset: the GPL still applies to this subset of the code.

Note that this is a grey area in some cases: are you only removing parts or making other substantive mods? Some level of modification make be such that you enter derivative work territory. Consult a lawyer!

/IANAL /TINLA